# How to map xml attribute values to java class attributes using jaxB or any other better method?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

### this is my test.xml and i want to tag attribute name values i.e bookid, bookname and noOfPages to attributes of Book.java class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:class xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/test" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/test test.xsd ">
<attr name="bookid" primary="true"/>
<attr name="bookname" primary="false"/>
<attr name="noOfPages" primary="false"/>
<attr name="auth_name" primary="false"/>
</tns:class>
```

---

### Book.java

```
package com.srl.rotelearning.test;

public class Book {

    private int bookId;
    private String bookname;
    private int noOfPages;

    public int getBookId() {
        return bookId;
    }

    public int getNoOfPages() {
        return noOfPages;
    }

    public void setNoOfPages(int noOfPages) {
        this.noOfPages = noOfPages;
    }

    public void setBookId(int bookId) {
        this.bookId = bookId;
    }

    public String getBookname() {
        return bookname;
    }

    public void setBookname(String bookname) {
        this.bookname = bookname;
    }

}
```

i tried using JAXB but i think we can map attribute names to class attributes. how do i map  xml attribute values to my class attributes?
 plz give ans in detail as m new to using xml thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) we offer this behaviour through our `@XmlPath` extension

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Book {

    @XmlPath("attr[@name='bookid']/text()")
    private int bookId;

    @XmlPath("attr[@name='bookname']/text()")
    private String bookname;

    @XmlPath("attr[@name='noOfPages']/text()")
    private int noOfPages;

}
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about this use case on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

Comment: thanks.. will try doing this. what dependencies are required for implementing this MOXy? do i need to install EclipseLink 2.3.0 ?